# How to sum up specific cells based on criteria established in a neighboring (nearby) cell?

Tags: google-sheets

The sheet is used to track hours spent on a project. I track the projects by the first letter of the project name (column a). The hours spent on the project is in column b. I'd like to separatley sum up all project hours for each project in column "e".

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything from Col D and Col E. Then place the following formula in D1:

`=QUERY({A:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col1 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'Project', SUM(Col2) 'Total Hours'")`

This is a pretty standard QUERY formula. Even if you are not familiar with QUERY, you should be able to understand in context of seeing what it produces.